# Speech Recognition in Clojure

Tags: text, clojure, speech-recognition, speech

I am new to clojure and am trying to use this library I found on github https://github.com/klutometis/speech-recognition

In the documentation it says to include a line of code inside a namespace but I am not sure of how to do that? Can anyone help?

Comment: When the README says *add to your `ns`*, it means the `ns` block at the top of one of your files of source code. If you're having trouble doing that... show what you tried, show how it failed (see the [mcve] page in the Help Center for guidance on what showing what you tried should look like). Without more details on how you're stuck, there's no guarantee that an answer we gave here would be more helpful than the README.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use is a legacy function of Clojure

```
(:use [speech-recognition.hear :as hear])
```

is same as

```
(:require [speech-recognition.hear :as hear])
```